# Call PopBackStackImmediate but keep a reference to the fragments in back stack?

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, xamarin.android

I am using an array to keep a reference to the fragments I add to fragment manager.
At some point I want to clear the back stack so I call fragmentmanager. PopBackStackImmediate.

The problem is that after calling this method, all fragments in my array become null.

The code I am using to add fragments in fragment manager and my array is from Xamarin.Android, but i believe the philosophy is similar to java:

```
        var newFragment = new Fragment();
        FragmentTransaction ft = FragmentManager.BeginTransaction();
        ft.Add (MainActivity.CONTENT_VIEW_ID, newFragment,"myid");
        ((MainActivity)this.Activity).FragmentsList.Add (newFragment);
        ft.AddToBackStack (null);
        ft.Commit ();
```

FragmentsList is the list where I hold a reference to each fragment I add to the fragment manager.

To clear the back stack I call:

```
FragmentManager.PopBackStackImmediate (null, PopBackStackFlags.Inclusive);
```

After calling this method, all my fragment references in the FragmentsList are destroyed.

Can I somehow keep a reference to the fragments in fragment manager after calling PopBackStackImmediate?

Comment: Trying to find a solution, I found that from API level 17, the Fragment contains the method: getChildFragmentManager. Using this object, I can maintain separate back stacks for each tab, but I have been not able to display the new fragments on screen using fragmentTransaction.Add method. If somebody has an example of nested fragments without using XML, but only code, this would help